# How do I make Google Sheets split function work properly with 3 characters and spaces?

Tags: google-sheets

I want Google Sheets to split the following delimited by "/":

`2 1 2/ 2 1 2/1 2 1 2/1 2 1 2/1 1 2/1 1 2`

This is the function I'm doing:

`=SPLIT(TO_TEXT(A6), "/", false)`

And this is the result (cells separated by |):

`37288|37288|1 2 1 2|1 2 1 2|37257|37257`

I don't know why it's converting certain groups of numbers into completely different numbers here.  It seems to only happen for the delimited entries that have 3 characters, if I add an extra character to these, it outputs as expected.  Any ideas?

I've tried the function with and without the [split_by_each] parameter.  I've tried TO_TEXT before splitting. I've tried changing the format to plain text.  I've tried changing delimiters.  None seem to work.  When I add an extra character to the delimited sections that only have 3, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When you split using the `SPLIT` function, Sheets automatically converts the datatypes of the values. In your case, it's interpreting them as dates. Use [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)-[`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) instead:

To split by `/` the formula would be:

```cpp
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.*?)(/|$)","($1)$2"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also try inserting an apostrophe at the beginning of each group:

```
=split("'"&substitute(A1,"/","/'"),"/")
```

[image]